# How to access a resource in Eclipse using a Java API

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

I imported a resource (resource being a GZIP file) into my Java project, but I'm not sure how I could access it from within the same project.

Java Resources -> srctest -> somepackagename -> MyClass.java (This is the class that wants to access the GZIP file)

Java Resources -> testdata -> someFile.gz

Comment: by resource, do you mean jar?

Comment: did you try unzipping the file, and then just putting the resulting code in a src directory in your code?

Comment: the gzip file has a bunch of folders and files in it that do not contain code. I also need to use the gzip file itself as I have a method that extracts the contents of the file to some directory.

Comment: what do you mean by "access a resource" from a gz file?

Comment: @Mark13426 , what exactly do you want to do accessing this GZIP file from within your Java code ? Read it as byte stream ? unzip it programmatically ? If you want to just read it , you can open an InputStream pointing to this file.. but is that you want ?

Comment: I have a method that unzips GZIP files and it works fine. Instead of typing a path name like "C:\\bla\\someFile.gz", I want to be able to embed a GZIP file in my project and open it as an InputStream. I need to do this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this -

```
InputSteam is =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/someFile.gz")
```

I am assuming the gzip file is on the same classpath as the current class.

Comment: is there a way to get the absolute path of this file? i need to pass it as a string to another method.

Comment: `URL location =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/test") ;
System.out.println("URL of resource " + location.getPath());`